# Reading email from Emacs VM using a secure server (Gmail)

Tags: windows, email, emacs, stunnel

This is a question (see below) originally entered at https://answers.launchpad.net/vm/+question/108267 and upon the recommendation of Uday Reddy the question and answers are being moved here.  The date of the original question was May 4, 2010.

One subject of the question is use of the program stunnel with program View Mail (run within Emacs) on a PC running Microsoft Windows, in order to read email from a server that requires use of TSL/SSL (Gmail).  See the related question, [How to configure Emacs smtp for secure server for using a secure server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699256/how-to-configure-emacs-smtp-for-using-a-secure-server-gmail), for sending email.

The programs discussed are Emacs, VM (ViewMail) and stunnel.  The platform under discussion is MS Windows.

---

*The original question was asked by usr345 on 2010-04-24:*

I tried to install vm on Windows, but when I tried to get the mail from gmail using ssl, an error emerges, emacs hanges-up. Here is the code from .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
             (expand-file-name "~/vm/lisp"))
(add-to-list 'Info-default-directory-list
             (expand-file-name "~/vm/info"))
(require 'vm-autoloads)

(setq vm-primary-inbox "~/mail/inbox.mbox")
(setq vm-crash-box "~/mail/inbox.crash.mbox")
(setq vm-spool-files `((,vm-primary-inbox
                            "pop-ssl:pop.gmail.com:995:pass:usr345:PASSWORD"
                            ,vm-crash-box)))
(setq vm-stunnel-program "g:/program files/stunnel/stunnel.exe")
```

So, the question:

- How to configure pop-ssl on Windows?

Comment: I think it would be better to split the "getting email" and "sending email" issues into separate questions.  I will open a new question for sending email.  Please restrict this one to "getting email".

Answer (score 3):

Emacs version 24 (currently on prerelease) has built-in support for SSL connections, but version 23 does not have it.  You can use an external stunnel program to provide an SSL link, through which Emacs can talk to the server.

The variable `vm-stunnel-program` is the right one to use for configuring VM to use such a program.  However, you need to make sure that you have a well-functioning stunnel program on your machine.  The Cygwin toolkit includes an stunnel program that works well.

This [page on wiredbytes.com](http://wiredbytes.com/node/8) gives instructions for testing your stunnel program, independently of Emacs and VM.  Make sure that your stunnel program works before plugging it into VM.